# Swift: How to test a variable is a SequenceType?

Tags: swift, xcode6

My intent is to check if a variable is of SequenceType

Here is the code:

```
let a = []
a is SequenceType
```

XCode 6 beta 5 playground flags these errors:

[image]

I also tried an alternative syntax:

```
a.isMemberOfClass(SequenceType)
```

This time XCode 6 beta 5 playground shows these errors:

[image]

I have two questions here:

1) What do these error messages mean in each case?

2) What is the proper to test `a` is a subclass of a certain type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't dynamically check for `SequenceType` conformance.

The compiler is trying to say that `SequenceType` has a `typealias Generator: GeneratorType` and a protocol with a type requirement (`typealias`) can only be used as a constraint on generic types, e.g.:

```
func doSomethingOnSequence <S: SequenceType> (seq: S) {
    for i in seq {
        println(i)
    }
}

doSomethingOnSequence(a)
```

Since you can use generics there's probably a better way than checking for types with `is`.

If you still want to try checking against a less generic type you're doing it right (just using the wrong types):

```
let a: Any = []

a is Range<Int>
a is [String]
// and so on...
```